# Show more of the_content posts while scrolling

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm using WordPress and I want to show just portion of the_content function for a single post then when user scroll the page, rest of the_content shows up. For example, like Facebook and Dzone. So, is it possible do do that using jQuery? Please, give me any hint or solution. I'm aware of infinite-scroll, but that not what I want to achieve.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on the specifics of what you want and how it differs from simply having the user scroll down the screen. Is there a *lot* of text? A lot of pictures? Is this just "cool" or is there a specific UX you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Exactly, the is a lot of text and I'm trying to break it down using the scrolling method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: I found the solution long time ago at this website:

http://tomsbigbox.com/wordpress-load-more-posts-on-page-scroll/